# JMeter - how to check if there are any failing assertions with BeanShell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to make my continuous integration system understand when a JMeter test has failed.

I am thinking of using the `stdout` logs for that.

Is there a way to check inside a BeanShell PostProcessor if there are failing assertions?

Then I can log a GUID or something like that to signify that the test has failed.
Also, any idea how to log to `stdout` and not only inside the log file? JMeter logs some info to `stdout` but I am not sure if a `log.error("code")` will go there.

If there is any easier way, feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [JMeter Test Elements execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) Post-Processors are being called **before** Assertions so you need Listener which is the last element
2. [Starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting

---

Assuming all above you need to add [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) with the following code:

```
prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
  if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
      println('Assertion failed')
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! :)